# Context not being over riden

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a set of factories where my more specific factories reimplement the inner workings of the most basic factory. I set up a simple example I'm processing in node and the results honestly confuse me a bit.

```
const fac1 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac1'
  };

  this.f1 = function () {
    return this.f2()
  };

  return {
    f1: this.f1.bind(protected)
  }
};

console.log('factory 1', fac1().f1());

const fac2 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac2'
  };

  return {
    f1: fac1().f1.bind(protected)
  }
}

console.log('factory 2', fac2().f1());

const fac3 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac3'
  };

  return {
    f1: fac1().f1.bind(protected)
  }
}

console.log('factory 3', fac3().f1());
```

yields:

factory 1 fac1

factory 2 fac1

factory 3 fac1

but if I change factory 1 to

```
const fac1 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac1'
  };

  this.f1 = function () {
    return this.f2()
  };

  return {
    f1: this.f1//.bind(protected)
  }
};

// console.log('factory 1', fac1().f1());
```

I get

factory 2 fac2

factory 3 fac3

Best I can figure is something in using the pre bound f1 from fac1 prevents rebinding it latter. But that seems to run counter to the purpose of bind.

- What am I missing?
- Is their a way to do this without leaving fac1
  unbound?
- This is starting to feel unclean to me, is this an
  antipatern?

Comment: I am confused as to your wanted behavior. How exactly do you want it to behave?

Comment: The original version should print

factory 1 fac1
factory 2 fac2
factory 3 fac3

Bigger picture I was trying to implement a series of services for different consumers where the individual consumers have different frameworks. So one service would be basic but for redux teams I wanted to create a redux version of the factory that produced a reducer and had publishing the events built into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `f1: fac1().f1.bind(protected)` in your `fac2` and `fac3`, which will always give you the `{ f1: this.f1.bind(protected) }` from `fac1`, which means you are always using the `protected` object from `fac1`.

Try using `f1: this.f1.bind(protected)` instead. Basically use the factory's own `protected` instead of always using `fac1`'s.

```js
const fac1 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac1'
  };

  this.f1 = function() {
    return this.f2()
  };

  return {
    f1: this.f1.bind(protected)
  }
};

console.log('factory 1', fac1().f1());

const fac2 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac2'
  };

  return {
    f1: this.f1.bind(protected)
  }
}

console.log('factory 2', fac2().f1());

const fac3 = () => {
  const protected = {
    f2: () => 'fac3'
  };

  return {
    f1: this.f1.bind(protected)
  }
}

console.log('factory 3', fac3().f1());
```

Comment: Ah I see what you did, I still have a bigger problem with scope that reveals but you answered the question I asked.